# Fail to implement a custom theme over Tailwindcss/Flowbite

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit, tauri, flowbite

I am trying to implement my custom theme into my application made with **Tauri**, **Sveltekit**/**Tailwindcss** & **Flowbite**.

However, I can see all the colors I have defined in `styles.css` and in `tailwind.config.css` available on the `<html>` tag, but the tailwind classes doesn't seem to apply on the `<body>` tag.

[image]
[image]

I can tell that the dark mode is working since the class dark is removed when I toggle it and the colors are switched to the one I've defined in my `styles.css` :root.

I can also say that tailwindcss is working since I can see the background color changing when I set `dark:bg-primary-300` for example.

It does **not** work when I set `dark:bg-background-800`.

Am I missing something ? Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks !

My configuration:

- `package.json`:

```js
"dependencies": {
   "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
   "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.27.7",
   "@tauri-apps/api": "^1.5.1",
   "flowbite": "^2.2.0",
   "flowbite-svelte": "^0.44.20",
   "tailwind-merge": "^2.1.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.1.1",
   "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^2.4.2",
   "@tauri-apps/cli": "^1.5.6",
   "@tsconfig/svelte": "^5.0.0",
   "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
   "postcss": "^8.4.32",
   "svelte": "^4.0.5",
   "svelte-check": "^3.4.6",
   "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6",
   "tslib": "^2.6.0",
   "typescript": "^5.0.2",
   "vite": "^4.4.4"
}
```

- `svelte.config.js`:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import {vitePreprocess} from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

const config = {
   kit: {
       adapter: adapter()
   },
   preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
};

export default config;
```

- `tailwind.config.js`:
  [image]
- `styles.css`:
  [image]
- `index.html`:
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider checking:

- `background-300` or `background.300` is properly configured as a `backgroundColor`/`color` value.
- The file that the `<body>` tag appears in is covered by the `content` file globs within the Tailwind configuration.
- String concatenation/interpolation is not used to construct the class name.

Comment: I'm not sure about the second point, so I added a screen of my index.html where the styles.css are loaded.
I believe the other points are well respected.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand what you meant by point 2. This is it !